# debugging javascript console error

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

[image: error]
I just got some big project and with error in console. there are many more than  scripts used at that page but error shows very little information. there are 25 scripts loading at page.  To give you an idea how many scripts they are you can see. :( 
[image: total scripts]

I have error in console but i can't find which original file, line number causing it. the error showing are in library. but i know it's not library bug it's caused by some other script. but this stack trace is very small. is there any tool or any other way where i can originally find from where it is originating.

let me know if further information is required.

Comment: Did you tried click on amsock.js:6. line no.6.

Comment: A variable that's supposed to hold a DOM element is `null`. You probably have some code that's using `document.getElementById()` to find an element, and then you're passing it to the `handleLoad` function, but the element it's looking for doesn't exist.

Comment: @Barmar i know that but look above included screenshot how can i find in which file which line where i am passing that null element. that's the question how i will find that line.

Comment: There's no trivial way to know. You have to examine the source code, and see where it sets the variables that it passes to each function. You can search for all uses of that variable, and set breakpoints at the places that assign it so you can examine the value. Or single-step through the code. It's a debugger, with many powerful features that can be used to trace a program.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on link "amstock.js" you will be redirect to that file and directly in the line that was causing the error. Always the upper file is which causes the problem, but some times because of a previous one.

In adition, the error maybe cause by an asynchronous call that leaves your variable in null and fill it after the line of the error was call, or just you are trying to access a wrong variable. Check that line.